# How to traversal an enum?

Tags: typescript

Type 'string' cannot be assigned to type 'online' | 'offline'.
I should be missing something，But I don't know how to do.

```
enum StatusOptions {
  ONLINE = 'ONLINE',
  OFFLINE = 'OFFLINE',
}
Object.keys(StatusOptions).map((item: keyof typeof StatusOptions) => {
    return {
      text: StatusOptions[key],
      value: item
    }
})
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It's not clear from the question. You're performing a `map()` operation but not assigning the result to anything...

Comment: `Object.keys` returns an array of `string`. Therefore your type for item, must be: `string`: `(item: string) => ({ text: "...", value: item })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Type 'string' cannot be assigned to type 'online' | 'offline'` results from a mistyped function parameter, which you pass into your map function.

`Object.keys` is defined as:

```js
    /**
     * Returns the names of the enumerable string properties and methods of an object.
     * @param o Object that contains the properties and methods. This can be an object that you created or an existing Document Object Model (DOM) object.
     */
    keys(o: object): string[];
```

Therefore you have to correctly type your function. Where item, is a `string`

```js
Object.keys(StatusOptions).map((item: string) => /* do something with it */);
```

Just in case you want then use the item as a key for StatusOptions like: `StatusOptions[item]`. You have to cast it as the following:

```js
Object.keys(StatusOptions).map((item: string) => {
    return {
      text: StatusOptions[item as keyof typeof StatusOptions],
      value: item
    }
})
```